# Symfony Save comments on blog with user and blogId

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2.8, I have created one-to-many relationship between user and blog,(one user many blogs). Also I have created one-to-many relationship between blog and comments. Similarly one-to-many relationship between user and comments as well. Now my comment table looks like this

**comment table**

```
id  Primary     int(11) 
user_id  Primary    int(11)
blog_id  Primary    int(11) 
comment             varchar(2000)  
created_at          datetime
```

**Comment Entity**

[Comment Entity](http://mysticpaste.com/OTX6aLvhhn)

**Blog Entity**

[Blog Entity](http://mysticpaste.com/hnTI3R3iSv)

**User Entity**

[User Entity](http://mysticpaste.com/1CrvMBvqHh)

**Blog controller -> ShowAction method**

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/show/{id}", name="blog_show")
 */
public function showAction(Request $request,$id)
{
    $blog = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Blog::class)->findOneById($id);
    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user = new User();
        $blog = new Blog();
        $comment->setUser($this->getUser());
        $comment->setBlog($blog);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('id' => $id)), 301);
    }

    return $this->render('Blog/show.html.twig', array('blog'=> $blog,'form' => $form->createView()));

}
```

Now when I submit the comment form from blog show page, it is showing me this error

```
"A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\Comment#blog' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AppBundle\Entity\Blog@0000000017546b06000000001fededdf. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'AppBundle\Entity\Blog#__toString()' to get a clue."
```

What I have missed here. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's telling you there's no function called `getBlog` in the class. Is that true?

Comment: If you check my Comment entity, there is one function defined getBlog(). But still its showing that error.

Comment: But that's in the `Comment` entity. When you call `$this->getBlog();` it's looking for that function in the `BlogController` itself. Do you need to get it from the form instead?

Comment: Oh Ok.. So how can I get getBlog() method from my Comment entity, I mean it should get current blog where the user submitted the comment.

Comment: Does the user select these values on the form? I think you need to check out this page: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/forms.html

Comment: Also these lines create new, empty objects that are then do nothing. `        $user = new User();
        $blog = new Blog();`.  I don't think that could be your intention.

Comment: Yes, It creates new empty objects, I want to save the $blogId using relationship. So I'm bit confused since comment is related with both user and blog.

Comment: You should retrieve existing Blog and User for this.

Comment: I have edited the showAction() method. See the first line now. Its the object of existing blog. Now when I submit the comment form, its showing me this error. I have posted new error on question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a variable called `$blogId` in your code, but assuming it is set, you can try:

[Edit: Follow your example to get `$blog`]

```
$blog = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Blog::class)->findOneById($id);

$comment->setBlog($blog);//Pass that entity to the CommentEntity
```

Comment: its showing me this error now, "A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\Comment#blog' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AppBundle\Entity\Blog@000000000e6df9e9000000000ffb3b56. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'AppBundle\Entity\Blog#__toString()' to get a clue."

Comment: This line was overriding $blog object "$blog = new Blog();" in the showaction method. I removed it and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Great! Good luck!