# Symfony set value 1 if admin Add the Comment

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2.8, I have status field in the comment table in database, so If admin add any comment from blog page, it should be saved 1 as status in the db. Now I'm saving comment data from showAction() method.

**showAction() method**

```
public function showAction(Request $request,$id)
{
    $blog = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Blog::class)->findOneById($id);
    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user = new User();
        $comment->setUser($this->getUser());
        $comment->setBlog($blog);
        if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $comment->setstatus(1);
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->merge($comment);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('id' => $id)), 301);
        //return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_list');
    }
    $comments = $blog->getComment($comment);

    return $this->render('Blog/show.html.twig', array('blog'=> $blog,'form' => $form->createView(),'comments'=>$comments));

}
```

Now if normal user add any comment, I have defined value 0 of status in Comment entity, so that it is automatically insert 0(PrePersist).

**Comment Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setStatusValue() {
    $this->status = 0;
}
/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param int $status
 * @return status
 */
public function setstatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return status 
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}
```

Now what I want is as per my showAction() method, I want the status 1 in comment table when Admin add any comment. Its storing 0 in both normal and admin user case. Any help is much appreciated.

More code is available at this question.. [Symfony Save comments on blog with user and blogId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445457/symfony-save-comments-on-blog-with-user-and-blogid)

Comment: If your route for add comment comes under admin firewall then you can check `isGranted` part otherwise it will always return false and teat it as a normal user

Comment: It is checking isGranted part. I have checked it.

Comment: See dump($comment) output, I have added it just below isGranted if condition here. http://mysticpaste.com/9STKB8DzpY

Comment: See the last line, its showing status 1, but not inserting 1 in status column of db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing setStatusValue() (Prepersist method) from comment entity and adding status from controller for both normal and admin user.

**showAction() method**

```
public function showAction(Request $request,$id)
{
    $blog = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Blog::class)->findOneById($id);
    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user = new User();
        $comment->setUser($this->getUser());
        $comment->setBlog($blog);
        $comment->setstatus(0);
        if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $comment->setstatus(1);
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->merge($comment);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('id' => $id)), 301);
    }
    $comments = $blog->getComment($comment);

    return $this->render('Blog/show.html.twig', array('blog'=> $blog,'form' => $form->createView(),'comments'=>$comments));

}
```